# MS Linq - left join foreign key table that has a nested foreign key table

Tags: linq

I get the following error running a query a possible null foreign key table with nested objects:

[image]

*"A valid ResultType could not be inferred from the ResultTypes of the specified 'Then' expressions."*

Is there a better way to write this that doesn't produce that error?

```
var ProductList = 
  (
  from P in AppDevModel.Product where ( P.IsDeleted == false )
    join RX in AppDevModel.RepoExt on P.RepoExtID equals RX.ID into tblWdRepoExt
    from RXwD in tblWdRepoExt.DefaultIfEmpty() // <-- Left join... some Products have no RepoExt
    
    orderby P.Name ascending

  select new ProductModel()
    {
     ID = P.ID
    ,RepoExtID      = P.RepoExtID
    ,Name           = P.Name
    ,RepoExt        = RXwD != null 
      ? new RepoExtModel()
        {
         ID         = RXwD.ID
        ,RepoTypeID = RXwD.RepoTypeID
        ,Name       = RXwD.Name
        ,RepoType   = ( from RT in AppDevModel.RepoType where ( RT.ID == RXwD.RepoTypeID ) 
                            select new RepoTypeModel() { ID = RT.ID, Name = RT.Name } ).FirstOrDefault<RepoTypeModel>()
        }
      : new RepoExtModel()
        {
         ID         = 0
        ,RepoTypeID = 0
        ,Name       = ""
        ,RepoType   = new RepoTypeModel { ID = 0, Name = "" }
        }
    }
  );

return ProductList;
```

Comment: You are rewriting SQL into LINQ. Terrible idea. Generally, `join` in LINQ statement is a very strong code smell. What is your model? What are you trying to get?

Comment: Not Complicated.  I am just to bring in all three tables. which are three levels of hierarchy.  I added a diagram.

Comment: @user5855178, show your classes with navigation properties, images are useless.

Comment: Would be easeir if you explain what you are trying to achieve from your query, there might be an easier way of writing it than trying to understand what you are tyring to do.

Comment: @user5855178 - you are thinking in terms of tables, and "translating" tables to LINQ. That's not how it works. If you want to stay in relational logic, then just use SQL. Or learn how to design the model in classes - and start development in LINQ. In this case you will find out that `join` won't be necessary - you will have navigation properties to connect the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution.. I just have to add the grandchild table with a Default.. I had left that out.

All tables from a withDefault table require a Default as well.. and a default class if you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do this as a query, something like the below.
I am not sure if this would be helpfull for you, but might worth having a look and give a try, might also be of use to someone else in the future:

Also, try the query and modify it before you use it in the code, use your prefered tool, i.e SSMS to test the results:

```
        using (var context = new YourDbContext(options))
        {
            List<Product> productList = context.Product
                .FromSqlRaw(@"
                    SELECT
                        P.ID,
                        P.RepoExtID,
                        P.Name,
                        CASE
                            WHEN RX.ID IS NOT NULL THEN
                                RX.ID,
                                RX.RepoTypeID,
                                RX.Name,
                                ISNULL(RT.ID, 0) AS RepoTypeID,
                                ISNULL(RT.Name, '') AS RepoTypeName
                            ELSE
                                0 AS ID,
                                0 AS RepoTypeID,
                                '' AS Name,
                                0 AS RepoTypeID,
                                '' AS RepoTypeName
                        END AS RepoType
                    FROM
                        AppDevModel.Product P
                    LEFT JOIN
                        AppDevModel.RepoExt RX ON P.RepoExtID = RX.ID
                    LEFT JOIN
                        AppDevModel.RepoType RT ON RX.RepoTypeID = RT.ID
                    WHERE
                        P.IsDeleted = 0
                    ORDER BY
                        P.Name;")
                .ToList();
        }
```